# A Relation between two converging sequences.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Assume that $\frac{a_n}{b_n} \to \ell$, where $\ell >0$.

Show there exists a number $c_1$ such that $a_n \leq c_1.b_n$ for all $n$ and $c_2$ such that $b_n \leq c_2.a_n$ for all $n$.

I apologize I could not put the question in the title, it was too long. I do understand the concept of convergence but I have no idea on how to attack this problem at all. Any guidance is appreciated thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the definition of the limit, there exists an integer $N$ such that
$$\left|\dfrac{a_n}{b_n}-l\right|<1$$
whenever $n>N$.
A bit of algebra shows then that
$$a_n\leq (l+1)b_n$$
for every $n>N$ so that we have found a constant $c=l+1$ such that $a_n\leq cb_n$ if $n>N$.

All we have left to do is to show that such an inequality holds when $0\leq n\leq N$. But there are only finitely many such integers $n$.

Edit: actually misread the question. This last bit will only work if for example both sequences are positive.

Answer (score 3):

**This is not true.**

Take $(a_n)= 1, 1, \dots$ and $(b_n)=0,1,1, \dots$. You won't be able to find $c_1$ such that $a_n \leq c_1.b_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$, as $a_1 >0$ and $b_1=0$.

Although this is true for $n$ large enough.